# openface accuracy decrease with each person i add

Tags: face-recognition

I created many classifiers with 2, 3, 10, 50 and 100 people, each with about 10 images per person.

Each person i add i get lower confidence.
I tested the 2 persons with the same training images and get 93%, I added 1 more person and the confidence went down to 90%.
When I use 100 persons, I get 44%.

Is it possible to get accuracy for that much people? eventually I want to add 50k or more people. does it scale?

What could be the problem?
I attached the images i used for 3 persons.
[link to images](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07094975847968375607)

I used these tutorials:

http://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/demo-3-classifier/

https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78#.9hcznhs7r

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this too.  And on thinking it through, there is no problem.  The confidence naturally decreases as the sample size increases because the features of the sum of people it is trained on marginally converge and so it can still identify the correct person but it is less certain.    I believe this is just a statistical phenomenon.